# How to get webimage without knowing the file extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image-processing, webimage

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 WebImage helper, I try to get a image like the following

```
var image = new WebImage("~/Content/Temp/" + user.id + ".jpg");
```

this only works when the file extension is jpg, how do you get the image if you are not sure what the file extension is, I also tried to use:

```
var image = new WebImage("~/Content/Temp/" + user.id + ".*");
```

but * is a invalid character.

Comment: You don't.  How can I introduce myself if i don't even know my own name?

Comment: @rism call me anything

Comment: Anything is still something. A Uri on the other uniquely identifies a resource right? * is not unique. How is the server supposed to serve it?

Comment: @rism but isn't there something to say that get the file regardless of its extension? so if i try to get a image by its name from a folder without knowing its extension, it is not possible?

Comment: No because you are asking the server to decide what you want which contrary to the idea of a request / url. REST based services have a weighted Accepts property which negotiates the content type returned but that's not dealing with what you want here. Since images are static files, the server is just looking for the resource and returning it. The extension is obviously an integral part of the overall address so you cant just omit it. You'd have to write an action and map images to asp.net and then have the action do the wild card look up on your behalf.